# Ruby Array: string into integer

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

I'm new to Ruby. I have a series of arrays with two strings each:

```
["[[\"Wayfair \", \"57\"]]", "[[\"Move24 \", \"26\"]]",
  "[[\"GetYourGuide \", \"25\"]]", "[[\"Visual Meta \", \"22\"]]",
  "[[\"FinLeap \", \"20\"]]", "[[\"Movinga \", \"20\"]]",
  "[[\"DCMN \", \"19\"]]", ...
```

I am trying to convert the string with the number of each array into an integer, but I get something else than I expect:

```
companies = companies.map do |company|
  c = company[0].scan(/(.+)\((\d+)\)/).inspect
  [c[0], c[1].to_i]
end
```

puts:

```
["[", 0], ["[", 0], ["[", 0], ["[", 0], ["[", 0], ["[", 0],
  ["[", 0], ["[", 0], ["[", 0], ["[", 0], ["[", 0]]
```

I am expecting:

```
 ["Wayfair", 57],  ["Move24", 26], ["GetYourGuide", 25], ...
```

please help?

Full code :

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI('http://berlinstartupjobs.com/') #URI takes just one url
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri) #get in URI
req['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36' #use this header


res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http| http.request(req)} # URI documentation

puts res.code #status code

puts res.body

puts res.body.scan('<a href="http://berlinstartupjobs.com/companies/') #scan in the body of the document files that match a href=...

puts res.body.scan(/<a href="http:\/\/berlinstartupjobs\.com\/companies\/[^\s]+ class="tag-link">(.*)<\/a>/) #scan

companies = res.body.scan(/<a href="http:\/\/berlinstartupjobs\.com\/companies\/[^\s]+ class="tag-link">(.*)<\/a>/)


companies = companies.map do |company|
  c = company[0].scan(/(.+)\((\d+)\)/).inspect
  [c[0], c[1].to_i]
end # do ... end = { }

  puts companies.inspect
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output too?

Comment: The way I see it, you have a flat array of strings.

Comment: Yeh, would be nice to see expected output

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've updated the question with full info.

Comment: @JenLijó: still it's not runnable.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, now it is. Sorry I didn't add the first part of the code by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was mostly ok. Just drop that `.inspect` at the end. It returns a string, not array.

```
# this is what you get from the scraping.
companies = [["Wayfair (57)"], ["Move24 (26)"], ["GetYourGuide (25)"]]

companies = companies.flatten.map do |company|
  c = company.scan(/(.+)\((\d+)\)/).flatten
  [c[0], c[1].to_i]
end

p companies
# >> [["Wayfair ", 57], ["Move24 ", 26], ["GetYourGuide ", 25], ...]
```

Comment: hey Sergio thank you so much - this is what I needed.

I had a feeling flatten was the quid and been playing with it, but not this way. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `Enumerable#map` & parsing each element using `JSON.parse`:

```
require 'json'

companies.map { |elem| key, val = JSON.parse(elem).flatten; [k.strip, v.to_i] }
```

Instead of `JSON.parse` you also can use `eval`, but using `eval` is considered to be a bad practice.

Comment: nah, his data is not like this. OP just messed up the printing.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ["[[\"Wayfair \", \"57\"]]", "[[\"Move24 \", \"26\"]]"]
result = arr.collect{|e| JSON.parse(e)[0].map{|name, value| [name.strip, value.to_i]}}

OUTPUT:
[[Wayfair, 57], [Move24", 26]]
```

Comment: nah, his data is not like this. OP just messed up the printing.